How to migrate data between orgs with a limit
I am using sfdmu (https://help.sfdmu.com/get-started) tool to migrate some data between two salesforce sandboxes. But my question is probably not related to the tool itself.
So suppose I have a large number of accounts and cases in Sandbox A. And I want to extract a subset of the accounts and cases into Sandbox B.
Something like:
Select Id, Name From Account Limit 100
Select Id, Name From Case Limit 100

However, since case are related to Account, it is hard to get 100 Cases associated with the 100 Accounts exported earlier. And this is just one simple model. We can have more than two SObjects to extract in this scenario.
Is there any solution to this?

https://help.sfdmu.com/faq/conceptual-definitions-in-sfdmu/what-is-master-and-what-is-slave
